# Check data condition with multiple row and get only single output value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

Check data condition with multiple row and get only single output value

```
Status
SUCCESSFULL
SUCCESSFULL
SUCCESSFULL
SUCCESSFULL
```

Then need Output "SUCCESSFULL"

IF any record have "Failed" status then output will be "Failed" as below

```
Status
SUCCESSFULL
SUCCESSFULL
FAILED
SUCCESSFULL
```

Then need Output "FAILED"

Comment: The tags surprise me. Does the PL/SQL Developer software really support SQL Server? And you are running two different versions of SQL Server?

Comment: @Rushang . . . I find it amusing that "successful" is misspelled, but "failed" is not.

Answer (score 1):

Are you merely looking for this:

```
select min(status) from mytable;
```

(`'FAILED'`  comes before `'SUCCESSFULL'` in the alphabet, so with `MIN` you get `'FAILED'` when at least one row is `'FAILED'` and `'SUCCESSFULL'` only if all rows are `'SUCCESSFULL'`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation functions `count()` and `sum()` to achieve this.

```
select 
    case when 
        sum(case when status = 'SUCCESSFULL' then 1 else 0 end)  = count(1) 
    then 'SUCCESSFULL' 
    else 'FAILED'
    end
from tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Status 
   FROM Your_table
      ORDER BY status
```

Comment: You should always describe your code how it is saying and how will this solve the OP requirement either in long or at least a short description.